# Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, sftp, pysftp

I would like to copy an entire directory structure with files and subfolders  recursively using SFTP from a Linux server to a local machine (both Windows and Linux) using Python 2.7.

I am able to ping the server and download the files using WinSCP from the same machine.

I tried the following code, works fine on Linux but not on Windows.

I tried `\`, `/`, `os.join`, all gives me same error, checked permissions as well.

```
import os
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None    # disable host key checking.
sftp=pysftp.Connection('xxxx.xxx.com', username='xxx', password='xxx', cnopts=cnopts)
sftp.get_r('/abc/def/ghi/klm/mno', 'C:\pqr', preserve_mtime=False)
```

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysftp_init_.py", line 311, in get_r preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysftp_init_.py", line 249, in get self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 769, in get with open(localpath, 'wb') as fl: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\pqr\\./abc/def/ghi/klm/mno/.nfs0000000615c569f500000004'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, pysftp `get_r` does not work on Windows. It uses `os.sep` and `os.path` functions for remote SFTP paths, what is wrong, as SFTP paths always use a forward slash.

But you can easily implement a portable replacement.

```
import os
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
```

```
def get_r_portable(sftp, remotedir, localdir, preserve_mtime=False):
    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remotedir):
        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry.filename
        localpath = os.path.join(localdir, entry.filename)
        mode = entry.st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            try:
                os.mkdir(localpath)
            except OSError:     
                pass
            get_r_portable(sftp, remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime)
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)
```

Use it like:

```
get_r_portable(sftp, '/abc/def/ghi/klm/mno', 'C:\\pqr', preserve_mtime=False)
```

---

Note that the above code can be easily modified to work with Paramiko directly, in case you do not want to use pysftp. The [Paramiko `SFTPClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient) also has the [`listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr) and [`get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) methods. The only difference is that the Paramiko's `get` does not have the `preserve_mtime` parameter/functionality (but it can be implemented easily, if you need it).

And you should use Paramiko instead of pysftp, as pysftp seems to be a dead project. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

---

Possible modifications of the code:

- [Do not download empty folders while downloading from SFTP server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56337086/850848)
- [Download files from SFTP server that are older than 5 days using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56287892/850848)
- [How to sync only the changed files from the remote directory using pysftp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47459065/850848)

---

*For a similar question about `put_r`, see:

[Python pysftp put_r does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58460718/850848)*

---

Side note: Do not *"disable host key checking"*. You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

For a correct solution, see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).