# To download the folder from sftp server, It downloading the folder in local directory but when i am giving particular file path then its showing error

Tags: python, operating-system, sftp, pysftp

I am attaching the below code please give the solution any one.

When I am giving the remote path such as: `/file/ICC1/log.txt`
and local path : `E:\abc`

Then it's showing error

> raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file

```
import os
import pysftp
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None    
sftp=pysftp.Connection('192.168.X.X', username='username',password='password',cnopts=cnopts)

def get_r_portable(sftp, remotedir, localdir, preserve_mtime=False):
    for entry in sftp.listdir(remotedir):
        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry
        localpath = os.path.join(localdir, entry)
        mode = sftp.stat(remotepath).st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            try:
                os.mkdir(localpath,mode=777)
            except OSError:     
                pass
            get_r_portable(sftp, remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime)
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)

remote_path=input("enter the remote_path: ")
local_path=input("enter the local_path: ")

get_r_portable(sftp, remote_path, local_path, preserve_mtime=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_r_portable` *(taken from [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848#50130813))* is for downloading a *folder*. Note that it starts with a listing of a remote directory given in the `remotedir` parameter: `sftp.listdir`.

So you cannot use it to download a single *file*.

To download a single file, use simple [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) (giving it paths to remote and local *files* as arguments):

```
remotepath = '/remote/path/file.txt'
localpath = r'c:\local\path\file.txt' 
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
```