# How can I only download files with timestamps in their names from the last 14 days from an SFTP?

Tags: python, datetime, sftp, pysftp

```
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import parser
import pysftp

lt_all = []

# disable hostkey checking
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

lt_all = []

srv = pysftp.Connection('sftp.com', username = 'username', password = "password", cnopts = cnopts)
srv.chdir('download')
server_file_list = srv.listdir()

for lt_file in server_file_list:
    if srv.isfile(lt_file) and ('invoices' in lt_file.lower() and 'daily' in lt_file.lower() and lt_file.endswith('.csv')):
        try: 
            srv.get(lt_file,os.path.join(os.path.join(data_folder_path,'Invoices'),lt_file),preserve_mtime=True)
        except:
            print("No Invoices Today")
```

The good news:
I have been successfully downloading all CSV files from the SFTP location.

The bad news: *all* CSV files are being downloaded.
Downloading 300+ files everyday is sub-optimal because downloading files that have already been downloaded is redundant.

These CSV files are generated daily. These files follow the same naming convention everyday: `invoices_daily_20200204.csv`. Notice the date comes at the very end in `yyyymmdd` format. Edit: The format is actually `mmddyy`.

How can I limit my downloads to only files created in the last 14 days? Is pysftp the best module for this?

Answer (score 1):

With your originally claimed fixed sortable timestamp format `yyyymmdd`, it would be easy. If you know that you will always have 14 files to download, use the solution by @lllrnr101. If this is not certain, generate a threshold file name with 14 days old timestamp and compare that against the file names in the listing:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d14ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(14)
ts = datetime.strftime(d14ago, '%Y%m%d')
threshold = f"invoices_daily_{ts}.csv"

for lt_file in server_file_list:
    if srv.isfile(lt_file) and (lt_file >= threshold):
        # Download
```

---

But it turned out that your timestamp format is `mmddyy` (`%m%d%y`), what is not lexicographically sortable. That complicates the solution. One thing you can do is to reorder the timestamp to make it lexicographically sortable:

```
ts = datetime.strftime(d14ago, '%m%d%y')

for lt_file in server_file_list:
    if srv.isfile(lt_file) and lt_file.startswith("invoices_daily_"):
        file_ts = lt_file[19:21] + lt_file[15:17] + lt_file[17:19]
        if file_ts >= ts:
            # Download
```

---

*Two side notes:*

- *Using [`Connection.isfile`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.isfile) for testing if the entry is file is inefficient. It requires a call to the server. While actually the [`Connection.listdir`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir) has that information already.*

  *Use [`Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) and `S_ISREG` test. For an example, see [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848#50130813)*.
- *Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have yyyymmdd naming format, why not just sort your server_file_list based on that and take the server_file_list[-14:] slice? A simple server_file_list.sort() will work since all names are same.

If you were not following the naming convention, you could use stat() method provided by pysftp to access the creation time and sort your entire server_file_list based on that. Then take the server_file_list[-14:] slice.

Comment: Do you have a functioning example of this method in git or stack overflow? @lllrnr101

Comment: Docs.python.org has the required documentation.