# Download multiple files from SFTP server using python in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, download, sftp, pysftp

The file download works well with individual files but when I run it in a for loop to download multiple files at once, it keeps crashing after downloading the first file. I tried multiple things but the result is same, the program stops after the first download with no error.

```
def store_files_name(fname):
    file_names.append(fname) 

def store_dir_name(dirname):
    dir_names.append(dirname)

def store_other_file_types(name):
    un_name.append(name)
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

conn = pysftp.Connection('', username='', password='', private_key=".ppk", cnopts=cnopts)
sftp.walktree("",store_files_name,store_dir_name,store_other_file_types,recurse=True)



for f in file_names:
    print(f)
    conn.get("/"+f)
```

Answer (score 0):

All pysftp recursive functions are known to be poorly implemented. They particularly do not work on Windows. They use `os.sep` and `os.path` functions for remote SFTP paths, what is wrong, as SFTP paths always use a forward slash.

And in general pysftp seems to be an abandoned project. Consider using Paramiko directly instead ([pysftp is just a thin wrapper around Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)).

For a working Paramiko code that iterates a remote folder, see:
[Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848)

Comment: Why update on this?